# Why is the JavaScript variable value not displaying?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to practice JavaScript and I wanted to output the variable in a created element. But the value stored in the variable is not output. Only the word answer. I console logged the variable and it has a number value in it. But it does not display only the word I do not know why?

```js
var name, computer, age, answer;

name = window.prompt("What is your name?");
alert("you chose " + name);

computer = window.prompt("How old where you when you used a computer");
alert(computer + "  0.0");

age = window.prompt("How old are you now?");
alert("you are " + age);

if (age - computer < 0) {
  age = 0;
  computer = 0;
}

answer = age - computer;

var con = document.getElementById('container');
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
var h1Text = document.createTextNode('answer');
h1.appendChild('h1Text');
con.appendChild('h1');

// document.write(age + " - " + computer + " = ");
// document.write(answer + "<br>");
```

```css
body {
  background-color: orange;
}

div {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 3em auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: instead of creating a text node, can't you edit the `innerText` property of the h1 tag?

Comment: I suggest you look at the JavaScript console. Your script causes an error. You should start there in figuring out how to fix your program.

Comment: `var h1Text = document.createTextNode('answer');
h1.appendChild('h1Text');
con.appendChild('h1');` -> `var h1Text = document.createTextNode(answer);
h1.appendChild(h1Text);
con.appendChild(h1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the string `answer` instead of the variable `answer` to `createTextNode` and hence answer text is being displayed, also `h1` and `h1Text` needs to be variable in

```
h1.appendChild(h1Text);
con.appendChild(h1);
```

Working snippet

```js
var name, computer, age, answer;

name = window.prompt("What is your name?");
alert("you chose " + name);

computer = window.prompt("How old where you when you used a computer");
alert(computer + "  0.0");

age = window.prompt("How old are you now?");
alert("you are " + age);

if (age - computer < 0) {
  age = 0;
  computer = 0;
}

answer = age - computer;

var con = document.getElementById('container');
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
var h1Text = document.createTextNode(answer);
h1.appendChild(h1Text);
con.appendChild(h1);

// document.write(age + " - " + computer + " = ");
// document.write(answer + "<br>");
```

```css
body {
  background-color: orange;
}

div {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 3em auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are not assigning the variable answer to anything.

Try

```
h1Text.innerHTML = answer;
```